# Twilio SMS PHP API

Tags: php, sms, twilio

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException' with     message 'SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain'
in C:\a_testsms\Services\Twilio\TinyHttp.php:119 
Stack trace: #0    
C:\a_testsms\Services\Twilio.php(179): Services_Twilio_TinyHttp->__call('post', Array) #1 
C:\a_testsms\Services\Twilio.php(179): Services_Twilio_TinyHttp->post('/2010-04-01/Acc...', Array, 'From=%2B1201419...') #2 
C:\a_testsms\Services\Twilio\ListResource.php(92): Base_Services_Twilio->createData('/2010-04-01/Acc...', Array) #3 
C:\a_testsms\Services\Twilio\Rest\Messages.php(24): Services_Twilio_ListResource->_create(Array) #4
C:\a_testsms\Services\Twilio\Rest\Messages.php(71): Services_Twilio_Rest_Messages->create(Array) #5
C:\a_testsms\sendnotifications.php(49): Services_Twilio_Rest_Messages->sendMessage('+12014196393', '+67573852595', 'Hellow Test, Te...') #6
{main} thrown in C:\a_testsms\Services\Twilio\TinyHttp.php on line 119
```

I am hoping if somebody could help me resolve the above Twilio API (PHP) error I am getting. My web application needs to send a sms after a customer completes the registration process. I downloaded the Twilio PHP helper library and also created the PHP script for the $id and $token variables. I also have the Twilio sms enabled phone number. I cannot seem to resolve this one on my own anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Please review this github response to your issue

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/issues/203

the TL;DR version is...

We’ve removed the pinned certificate chain from the library as it caused problems when we replaced expired certificates in the API servers. You’ll need to ensure your PHP installation has access to a recent bundle of CA certificates so it can verify the server certificates. Here’s a quick rundown: http://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/

Comment: Appreciate the information you provided. I will look into it and get back once I have resolved the issue.